# sorting process of PIG when there are many small input files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I saw this on hadoop web UI about a map task

```
Total Length = 67108863
Input split[0]:
   Length = 48334
  Locations:

-----------------------
Input split[1]:
   Length = 48334
  Locations:

-----------------------
Input split[2]:
   Length = 48304
  Locations:

...

-----------------------
Input split[2010]:
   Length = 23388
  Locations:

-----------------------
Input split[2011]:
   Length = 23383
  Locations:

-----------------------
```

I'm using pig and I know that pig combines small input files up to pig.maxCombinedSplitSize for efficiency

OK...but it seems to me that pig execution engine 'sorts' all the input files by their size and combine them to 64mb block for map task.

And I think this causes a big problem because I have currently millions of files for test data and hundreds of millions of files in real server, because when the system developer didn't consider possibility for using hadoop at that time.

There's no way to combine the small input files in real server, so I have to somehow make it out with PIG. and I think the sorting process is absolutely unnecessary and should be removed. So I'm now trying to find where that process exists in the PIG source code but have difficulty in doing that.

Does anybody know why PIG sort small input files when combining, and where that part of source code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that pig sorts the input files by size - I'm not sure why it does that. Why not merge the files in Hadoop w/o pig?  Some options are listed here: http://jugnu-life.blogspot.com/2013/01/merging-small-files-in-hadoop.html

Comment: Why do small input files makes map process much slower? say some mappers are finished in 10seconds but several mappers which contain processing thousand of input files takes about an hour. Is this because of network I/O? any related document?

Comment: Are all files on HDFS or on other FS?